# LYX equation numbers not synchronized properly between editor and output when mixing WYSIWIG with LATEX equations

Tags: equations, numbering, lyx

I'm writing a paper in LYX.  All my equations are numbered and entered with the built-in wysiwyg math editor, except for one which I had to enter as LATEX.  This messed up the numbering in the editor which didn't count the LATEX equation, but the output pdf was fine.  In the output pdf file equation numbers are larger by 1 than the equations in the editor after the LATEX equation.  There must be a different counter in the lyx editor for equations than in the LATEX output.  How can I synchronize them properly? For example, can I write a macro to add 1 to the editor's counter without changing the LATEX counter?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  although there are people here who are familiar with lyx (i'm not), this seems a question more suited for asking directly on the lyx site.  (it's a quite interesting question!)

Comment: Why did you need to write that one equation as code? (I.e., what was it you couldn't do via the GUI?)

Comment: Similar to the comment above, note that you can go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste from LaTeX when you paste LaTeX into LyX. This will *attempt* to turn it into native LyX format, which would correct the equation numbering.

Comment: I had a long equation that spilled over onto another line.  When I tried various methods to break the line into two in LYX it always turned out that something was wrong or ugly with the format.  The two lines of the equation looked too close together for my aesthetic sense.  So I resized the two lines, and put an extra 2mm  vertical space between them.  Now they look much better, but I have the equation number synchronization problem that I don't like.

Comment: May I ask exactly how you did it? For example, was it `\begin{multlined} first part \\[2mm] second part \end{multlined}`? (Asking as I was wondering if there might be other ways of achieving the same in LyX.)

Comment: By the way, if you want to notify a user, as you are notified of these comments, write an `@` followed by the username, e.g. @MarkDavidson. When you start typing the username after the `@`, a box with the name should appear and you can hit the tab-key to complete it. Only one user per comment can be notified though.

Comment: Here is how I did it:  (I used an array because it looked better than I could obtain using multiline techniques)                                        \large
\begin{equation} 
\mathnormal{\begin{array}{c} F^{\mu\nu}(x)=\frac{q}{V_{B}(s)\cdot\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)}\\[2mm] \times\frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)^{\mu}V_{B}^{\nu}(s)-\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)^{\nu}V_{B}^{\mu}(s)}{V_{B}(s)\cdot\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)}\right]\mid_{s=s_{r}} \end{array}} \end{equation}
\normalsize

Comment: If I copy the LaTeX code in your comment in my browser and in LyX I go to Edit > Paste Special > Paste from LaTeX, LyX recognizes it, and it compiles to PDF without error.

Comment: Note that when I compile that LaTeX manually, I get an error. Similarly LyX complains that something is wrong with it, so I'm guessing the output might need to be tweaked in some way after pasting into LyX.

Comment: I got no errors in either lyx for in pdflatex working from an exported TEX file.  The only problems I have is that the insert latex equation does not get counted as a numbered equation in the LYX wysiwig editor, but it does get counted in the numbering of the output pdf file.  This was the case both for lyx created pdf as well as Miktex created pdf.

Comment: Isn't a `gathered` environment inside an `equation` environment just as good? Or `aligned`.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this doesn't answer your question, so I can delete it if you'd like me to. But as an extension of my last comment: At the end of this post you'll find a sample `.lyx` file. It demonstrates your method, as well as using either a `gathered` or an `align` environment instead of `array`. Both those environments are available via the GUI, either via the Insert --> Math menu, or by right clicking in an equation and looking under Insert.

Compared to the `array`, the increase in font size isn't necessary because it doesn't use `\textstyle` (or whatever `array` does), and the `[2mm]` isn't necessary because there is more space between the lines by default than what `array` does.

Here is a screenshot showing the three approaches. Personally I'd probably use the third one. Note I replaced the `\mid` with `\biggr|`.

[image: result of lyx file]

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
Your method:
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
large
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{equation}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
begin{array}{c}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout

 F^{
\backslash
mu
\backslash
nu}(x)=
\backslash
frac{q}{V_{B}(s)
\backslash
cdot
\backslash
left(x-X_{B}(s)
\backslash
right)}
\backslash

\backslash
[2mm]
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
times
\backslash
frac{d}{ds}
\backslash
left[
\backslash
frac{
\backslash
left(x-X_{B}(s)
\backslash
right)^{
\backslash
mu}V_{B}^{
\backslash
nu}(s)-
\backslash
left(x-X_{B}(s)
\backslash
right)^{
\backslash
nu}V_{B}^{
\backslash
mu}(s)}{V_{B}(s)
\backslash
cdot
\backslash
left(x-X_{B}(s)
\backslash
right)}
\backslash
right]
\backslash
mid_{s=s_{r}} 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{array}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
end{equation}
\end_layout

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
normalsize
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Alternative approach 1:
\begin_inset Formula 
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}F^{\mu\nu}(x)=\frac{q}{V_{B}(s)\cdot\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)}\\
\times\frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)^{\mu}V_{B}^{\nu}(s)-\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)^{\nu}V_{B}^{\mu}(s)}{V_{B}(s)\cdot\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)}\right]\biggr|_{s=s_{r}}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Alternative approach 2:
\begin_inset Formula 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}F^{\mu\nu}(x) & =\frac{q}{V_{B}(s)\cdot\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)}\\
 & \qquad\times\frac{d}{ds}\left[\frac{\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)^{\mu}V_{B}^{\nu}(s)-\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)^{\nu}V_{B}^{\mu}(s)}{V_{B}(s)\cdot\left(x-X_{B}(s)\right)}\right]\biggr|_{s=s_{r}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Torbjorn, Thanks a lot.  I like your third example.  I'll use it in my paper.  That solves my problem.